# How to stick this div to bottom of page

Tags: css

Okay, so I'm trying to use CSS3 to stick this footer to the bottom of the page. Does anyone know how I would stick it to the bottom easily?

Thanks in advance
-Jaydon.

```
    width:19%;
    height:7%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0; 
    bottom 0px;
```

I've looked everywhere :'(

Comment: Do you want to have it stick to the bottom of your screen? (Stay the same place on the screen even when you scroll like a HUD) or do you want it at the bottom of your content? Or something else?

Comment: Try position: absolute or fixed and put it directly under the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:fixed` - example at http://jsfiddle.net/VFX9L/

```
#footer {
    width:19%;
    height:7%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px; 
    background-color:#F00; 
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it it if you want, it's like @sinisterfrog says.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/du3ya/1/)

```
html, body{padding:0;margin:0;}
#footer {
    height:10%;
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0; 
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
     -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px; 
    background-color:#B1EBBA; 
}

p{padding:10px;margin:15px 0;}
```